# Android Glide error: cannot find symbol method crossFade()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide

I am getting `cannot resolve symbol method crossFade()` error in Glide when trying to display an image from a Gmail account.

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        if(acct.getPhotoUrl() != null){

            personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        }
        String email = acct.getEmail();

        Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);
        txtName.setText(personName);
        txtEmail.setText(email);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl).thumbnail(0.5f).crossFade().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(imgProfilePic);


        updateUI(true);
    }
    else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
```

Note that `crossFade()` appears in red in my Android Studio as in the following image:

[image: screenshot]
I tried the following solutions from Stack Overflow but none of them worked for me.

- [Error:(59, 17) error: cannot find symbol method crossFade()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343309/error59-17-error-cannot-find-symbol-method-crossfade)
- [error: cannot find symbol method crossFade() in 4.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463988/error-cannot-find-symbol-method-crossfade-in-4-7-1)
- [Glide-4.0.0 Missing placeholder, error, GlideApp and does not resolve its method placeholder,error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481756/glide-4-0-0-missing-placeholder-error-glideapp-and-does-not-resolve-its-method)

How can I overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda old but if other person stuck 
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl).thumbnail(0.5f).crossFade().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(imgProfilePic);

change to

Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl).thumbnail(0.5f).transition(withCrossFade()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(imgProfilePic);